# Grunt Bower jquery.min.map Error. Setting up my first MEAN app

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mean.io

I'm trying to setup a MEAN environment. I keep getting this error:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/home/user/app1/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map'

I've tried on CentOS7 and RHEL6, on CentOS I tried installing nodejs from source and also from epel. On RHEL6 I used this method to setup nodejs:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
npm install -g mean-cli

mean init app1
cd app1 && node install

grunt
<error>
```

When I tried `bower install` I got `Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128` on bower install. To fix this run this command `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` I'm not sure if it is persistent.

That fixed the problem on RHEL6 but it didn't fix it on CentOS7. I went back to CentOS7 and tried again and it seems to have worked... I'm just going to move on and not question it for now.

Comment: did you try `bower install`? just before `grunt`.

Comment: Thanx for the edit. I did on the CentOS7 system. I also tried installing it globally as root and as a user in the app directory and got the same error. I also tried downloading the map file and jquery file from the jquery site and created the directory structure that was needed but that led to another error. Then I gave up and tried it on RHEL6. I did not do bower install on RHEL, but I am doing it now.

Comment: What is the error after you change git:// to https://?

Comment: I don't remember the error I got last night. But I tried it again now and it worked. I was running as root then. probably related to that. Thanks for the input

Comment: My new mean.io app only runs on 127.0.0.1 on a RHEL6 system. But on a CentOS7 system it binds to the actual routable interface.

I can't figure out where to configure the desired interface in the new mean.io application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to run `bower install` to download those dependencies. You'll have bower.json and maybe package.json (since you are running `npm install`) in your project root specifying the project dependencies.

Comment: This should be on MEAN documentation. Thanks